# Get Updated value of an bool data

Tags: angular, class, object, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am using angular 2. i made a service and i want to perform a simple task just like , i made object of service at in two components. at where component1 change the bool value to true at i want to use that value as it is in component2. same as vice versa.

My Service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class JwtService {

   appStatus:boolean=false;


  setStatus(value){
    debugger;

    this.appStatus = value;

  }
  getStatus(){


    return this.appStatus;
  }



}
```

At My component 1:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { JwtService} from '../shared/services/jwt.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [JwtService ]
})
export class AppComponent {





appStatus: boolean = false; 
 constructor( private jwtService:JwtService) { }


 public Func() :any{


      this.jwtService.setStatus(false);


    }

}
```

At My component 2:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtService} from '../services/jwt.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'layout-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  providers: [JwtService]
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    appStatus: boolean ; 
  constructor(  private jwtservice:JwtService

  ) { 
this.appStatus=jwtservice.getStatus();

   }

 setout()
{



  this.jwtservice.setStatus(true);


}



}
```

Just want to get changed value of appstatus presented at service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing `service` at `component` level, provide it at your `module` level. In this way your `service` will become singleton and changing the values at one `component` will be reflected in another `component`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],

  providers: [JwtService],

  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: @Haseoh -->You forgot to mention, that you have to provide JwtService in NgModule and delete providers: [JwtService] from both components. This way there will be one instance of JwtService for each components instead of 2 separe services.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not very familiar with RxJS.
You can transform `appStatus` to `Subject` which you can subscribe to. Basically, you pass callback to`Subject` which gets called every time value changes. `Subject.next(value)` is used to set new value.

**Note**: You **MUST** unsubscribe from subject when component gets destroyed. This will prevent memory leaks and undefined behavior.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtService {
   appStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
}
```

Both components:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _sub: Subscription;
  private _currentStatus: boolean = false;
  constructor(private service:JwtService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // We make subscription here. Behavior subject means that you will receive latest value on subscription and every next value when it is changed.
    this._sub = this.service.appStatus.subscribe((status) => this._currentStatus = status);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // IMPORTANT: UNSUBSCRIBE WHEN COMPONENT IS DESTROYED
    this._sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  setStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.service.appStatus.next(status);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it , Why this part is not working.
 this.subscription = this.jwtservice.appStatus.subscribe(message => console.log("Hello"+message));

Comment: You forgot to mention, that you have to provide `JwtService` in `NgModule` and delete `providers: [JwtService]` from both components. This way there will be one instance of `JwtService` for each components instead of 2 separe services.

Comment: @Haseoh I do not know if OP uses ng2 >1.0.0rc5.

Comment: @mehul You retyped something wrong, working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/T9YPg2SGHW099j6TsQoH?p=preview

Comment: Maybe you have service in `jwtservice` instead of `service`?

Comment: @Haseoh , Thanks, The above comment is really helped, worked with making it as singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `behaviourSubject`, reference can be found [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject).

What you should do is made `appStatus` in your service as a `behaviourSubject`. Then you will subscribe to its value from your component2. Now when you set its status in component1, component2 will detect the changed value and the function inside the subscription in component2 will be triggered.